# Regex to locate a specific sentence fragment but there may be an underscore some where in the string

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to find a string that may exist in a Windows menu item. As such a simple text search is complicated by the potential presence of an underscore character, which may be anywhere in the string. For example, I may be looking for "Import File" but the resulting string may be any of the following strings.

These are easy enough:

```
Import File
_Import File
```

But these elude simple grepping:

```
I_mport _File
Im_port File
Impor_t File
```

This works but it's clunky and prone to error, and it means that every time I need to look for a new menu item, I have to completely reconstruct the pattern. Is there an easier way?

```
I_{0,1}m_{0,1}p_{0,1}o_{0,1}r_{0,1}t _{0,1}F_{0,1}i_{0,1}l_{0,1}e
```

This is the regex tester URL: https://regex101.com/r/7ptBHG/2
UPDATED regex tester URL: https://regex101.com/r/7ptBHG/3

I'm using the VS2015 editor's "Use Regular Expressions" feature.

UPDATE -> RESPONSE TO QUESTIONS:
I hadn't considered using the ? instead of {0,1} That does make it a bit less cumbersome.

```
I_?m_?p_?o_?r_?t _?F_?i_?l_?e
```

If you proved an answer, I'll accept that. I did ask, "Is there an easier way?".

Comment: There is no other way. Just use `?` instead of `{0,1}`.

Comment: You can manipulate the pattern dynamically, adding `_?` after every character without doing it manually.

Comment: This works. Using the replace feature, search for (\w) and replace with _?$1 will create the search string for me. Be sure to just high light the one menu item string I'm looking for though. Thank you @horcrux.